# VBA Automatically start and stop refreshing clock

Tags: excel, vba

I have the following to display time, which runs dynamically:

```
Option Explicit

Dim SchedRecalc As Date

Sub Recalc()
With Sheet1.Range("D4")
.Value = Format(Time, "hh:mm:ss AM/PM")
End With
Call SetTime
End Sub
Sub SetTime()
SchedRecalc = Now + TimeValue("00:00:01")
Application.OnTime SchedRecalc, "Recalc"
End Sub
Sub Disable()
On Error Resume Next
Application.OnTime EarliestTime:=SchedRecalc, Procedure:="Recalc", Schedule:=False
End Sub
```

Having got this from instructions found online, this code sits on both an independent module, and within Sheet1.

It worked, but was causing the workbook to reopen automatically every time it was closed. Exiting the programme was the only way to close.

I then added to ThisWorkbook:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)
    Call Disable
End Sub
```

This does enable the workbook to close as normal, but now on reopening the clock does not refresh unless I restart the macro in the desired cell.

How can I have the clock refreshing straight away after opening the workbook without it causing the reopening issue?

Thank you...

Comment: Find materials on workbook open events.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Workbook_Open()` event to initialize the `onTime` process.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Call SetTime
End Sub
```